# Sharepoint online - missing DlpSensitiveTypes in API?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, office365api, sharepoint-api

My goal is to get the sensitive type or dlp policy name that matches a sharepoint file via REST.

As a test I have created a DLP policy in the Office365 portal and called it "my policy". It included 2 sensitive types to match. I uploaded a doc that matches this policy (i.e. contains the 2 types).

So far I was able to get the "ClassificationType" in the selected properties, but it gives me an ID that is not contained in the list of the sensitive types.

My query is as follows:

> https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/search/_api/search/query?querytext='ViewableByExternalUsers:true'&selectproperties='ClassificationType'

I'm getting back the following:

```
 "Key": "ClassificationType",

 "Value": "e09c07d3-66e5-4783-989d-49ac62748f5f",

 "ValueType": "Edm.String"
```

So, the value is ID and not name, I would like to get the either custom policy name that I defined ("my policy") or the sensitive type name.

Generating the list of IDs of the sensitive types by

> https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{my-tenant}/activity/feed/resources/dlpSensitiveTypes

e09c07d3-66e5-4783-989d-49ac62748f5f is not one of the type ids.

I found out that this ID belongs to "EU Tax Identification Number" which is not on the list. As well as other 4 IDs. So the missing IDs are:

- EU Driver's License Number
- EU National Identification Number
- EU Passport Number
- EU Social Security Number or Equivalent ID
- EU Tax Identification Number

Is this a bug in the API or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

"[DLP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference) sensitive data is only available in the activity feed API to users that have been granted “Read DLP sensitive data” permissions"

I don't think you can use SharePoint REST API to get the DLP matched policy type.

However, there is a tricky way you can try:

1. Set up in your policy. Send email once file matched the DLP policy.
   [image]
2. Use graph API to load the unread content and find out the content which will match the customized email text.
3. Then find out the DLP type.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I'm not using SharePoint rest but rather the management endpoint. I'm now just wondering why 5 types are missing .

Comment: I'm afraid that this function is not added into Graph API or PS(I presume the management endpoint you mentioned is powershell). I've check graph explorer, I can see the dataLossPrevention and notify inside it, however there is empty in the notify. I do recommend you raise a ticket in GitHub SharePoint Online (SPFx Dev team do track bugs in their "sp-dev-docs" repository or MS user voice)